# Cant connect to remote MS Access database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I keep getting a

InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.]

It is because my connection is closed.  What is wrong with my connection string? Why won't it open.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declaration section

        //OleDbConnection objDBConn;
        OleDbCommand    objCmd;
        OleDbDataReader objDR;

        //create connection object
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();

        // Modify the connection string and include any
        // additional required properties for your database.
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            @"Data source= c:\inetpub\wwwroot\cm485a2\rreAccesscm485a2.mdb";

          // Create OleDbCommand object with SQL to execute
            objCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * " +
                            "  FROM customers " +
                            " ORDER BY cust_id", conn);

            // Create a DataReader and execute the command
            objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Copy results from DataReader to DataGrid object
            GridView1.DataSource = objDR;
            GridView1.DataBind();


            //close all objects
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Try to connect outside of code. The " " after the "=" in the CS may be enough to make it not work (it does with other values). Also try an explicit `conn.Open` before using it. Sometimes it auto-opens, sometimes not and I'm not sure what the rules are -- doing it first won't hurt and will by symmetrical with the `conn.Close` (consider using a `using`)

Comment: This access db doesn't seem to be remote....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to Open the connection first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.open.aspx

also, I would use `using` to be avoid resource leaks, something like this:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection())
{
  connection.Open();
  using (var command = new OleDbCommand("connectionString"))
  {
     //Do my stuff.
  }
}
```

This ways is easier to leave resources uncollected by the GC.

HTH

Comment: Yeah, uhm. . . wow.  I think I was looking at it too long.  When I came back to my computer as soon as you said it I felt like an idiot. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Okay, so I got another question: How come my string is not getting accepted?  I actually changed the path, so I know it is the correct path:  'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\129.2.168.163\cm485a2\rreAccesscm485a2.mdb' is not a valid path. Any ideas?

Comment: Mike, check: http://www.connectionstrings.com/. maybe the .mdb file is locked or you don't have permissions. Hard to say. I would use a simpler path like C:\myStuff\DB\rreAccesscm485a2.mdb.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call conn.Open() after you set your connection string.

Edit: Woops, Markust beat me to it by 40 seconds, xD

Answer (score -1):

change your connection string as follows...

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
            @"Data source= c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\cm485a2\\rreAccesscm485a2.mdb";

*note: '\\' instead of '\'
```

Comment: The OP and your code example use the string literal character `@` which tells the compiler to take \ literally instead of treating it as the escape variable. Here's some official documentation on string literals. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)